# How to get post meta meta key and meta value of wp color picker field

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, metadata, meta-boxes

I have created an input field in my custom metabox and linked it to wpColorPicker object in jquery so that it becomes a color picker field.But i dont know to get the meta key to show the value.My code is:

```
<label for="title-background-color">Choose background color: </label>
<input  type="text" name="title-background-color" id="title-background-color" 
class="title-background-color" value="#dddddd" data-default-color="#dddddd">
```

I want to show it here

```
    <div class="post-title-under-header" style="background: `i want that value here` ;">
                <div class="post-title-under-header">
                    <?php the_title('<h1>', '</h1>');?>
                </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I think you can do it with Javascript

Comment: @Marco Mura i need the value thats all.And i dont think its a JavaScript thing.

Answer (score 1):

To set the background color of your element with class `post-title-under-header` you can do something like this with jQuery. The background-color will, in this example, change on an `change` event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#title-background-color').on('change',function(){
       $('.post-title-under-header').css('background-color',$('#title-background-color').val());
       });
   });
```

Comment: It's not Javascript ah u_u +1

Comment: Uhuh, it is in fact JavaScript ;) jQuery is a cute little library - and it fits the tags of the thread owner. Thanks for the +1.